# How to get all form attributes present in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want attributes like name, Id of forms present in a div

```
<div id="searchForms">

    <form id="form1" name="form1">    
    </form>

    <form id="form2" name="form2">    
    </form>
</div>

<form id="form3" name="form3">    
</form>
```

So what presently I am doing

```
$('form').each(function () {

    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));

});
```

But the problem is that it is giving me the name and id's of all the three forms. I want the name and id's of all the forms present in the div whose id is `id="searchForms"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/), use the id of parent div that is `searchForms` as `ancestor` and form as `descendant`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LCeQz/)**

```
$('#searchForms form').each(function () {    
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));    
});
```

**Description:** Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it worked for me. +1 for you.